# Supervisor turning server off when webhook is made

Tags: nginx, github, flask, webhooks, supervisord

I have the following route that gets called by Github when a push event is made to `github-repo`:

```
@app.route('/webhooks/github', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def github():
    result = subprocess.run(['bash', 'update'],
                            cwd=f'/home/',
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    return '', 200
```

The `update` script is in the `home` directory and it looks like this:

```
main() {
  cd /home/github-repo
  source venv/bin/activate
  git pull
  supervisorctl stop github-repo
  supervisorctl start github-repo
  return 0
}

main
```

What I'm finding when this runs is that `supervisor` stops but never executes the `start` command:

```
supervisorctl status

github-repo                   STOPPED
```

**Am I missing something here?**

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I should be using

```
supervisorctl reload github-repo
```

instead of `stop` and `start`.